# How can I recover the key from RIJNDAEL 128?

Tags: php, security, cryptography, rijndael

I have code like this:

```
$result = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plain_text, "ecb");
```

Also, I have values of $result and $plain_text.

Is there any way to recover the $key?

Comment: That would be a plain-text attack on aes, see http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/why-is-aes-resistant-to-known-plaintext-attacks

Comment: Unless you have the key, you're not going to be bruteforcing AES 128 this decade at least.

Comment: Or see also: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5355/compute-the-aes-encryption-key-given-the-plaintext-and-its-ciphertext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot recover the key from direct cryptanalysis.

You can use known-plaintext attacks to correlate known/repeated ciphertexts, especially if ECB mode is being reused. You can use Vaudenay's CBC padding oracle attack to decrypt a message one byte at a time (via a chosen ciphertext attack). You can exploit a CTR mode nonce reuse to recover plaintext from ciphertext.

You cannot simply recover the key given plaintext and ciphertext.

There *are* side-channel attacks, such as [cache-timing attacks against AES](https://cr.yp.to/antiforgery/cachetiming-20050414.pdf) (PDF), which allow an attacker to recover the key. But if you're using constant-time AES (i.e. provided by AES-NI), then these are off the table.

Comment: Note that Vaudenay's CBC padding oracle attack only works for CBC mode and only if the decryption method returns padding errors, it shouldn't, that would be an implementation error.

Comment: Right. The point I was trying to make was: None of these attacks recover the key. :)

Comment: True that none recover the key and that is a valid and important point. My issue is that I see "CBC padding oracle" thrown around often as if just using CBC mode is all that is necessary when in fact there must also be an implementation error by the developer.